# How do I import images using universal-webpack?

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, universal-react

I am trying to render a react application on the server using universal-webpack.

I have many pieces of the puzzle working, however I am unable to import images within my code.

If I have the code

```
import catPic from 'cat.png'
```

in one of my react components, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: cat.png: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
```

Is there something that I should look for in my configuration or server.js?

Comment: What is your editor : Atom , Sublime, Vim , Eclipse , NetBeans, .... ?

Comment: Atom is my editor

Comment: Note that I have the same issue with .css, .svg files that I am importing.

Comment: Ctrl+F .. search on � ,, and replace it with nothing... it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added a Webpack `file-loader` for `PNG` images